# How to make app useable across multiple Firebase Projects?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I just started building my first Firebase app.  The docs say to pass your projects credentials and URLs to `firebase.initializeApp()`, which is fine if you only have one project:

```
let app = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey              : "...",
    authDomain          : "<project_id>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL         : "https://<project_id>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket       : "<project_id>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId   : "...",
});
```

However, the docs also demonstrate the practice of creating multiple projects to represent the standard environments such as *dev*, *staging*, and *production*, which makes sense, as you don't want to be developing against the production database.

So, how do I write my initialization code in a credential-agnostic way, and then feed in the appropriate credentials for the project it is run within or deployed to?

Comment: Don't create multiple projects to represent the standard environments. Create multiple apps within the same project.

Comment: That doesn't fit with my understanding of Firebase.  Multiple apps in the same project share the same accounts and database.  The idea is you can have both a web app and a mobile app with the same users and content.

Comment: See https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html

Comment: Most of the info in that article is specific to Android apps.  I'm building a web app.